# How to load HTML after content has been loaded

Tags: javascript, java, html

I am trying to get a list of the content on a website ([this one](https://www.br.de/mediathek/podcast/sender/bayern-1) if anyone is interested). The layout has changed recently and now they do not load the content all at once, but with magic (js probably). I'm currently using [JSoup](https://jsoup.org/) to analyze the HTML, but im open to suggestions.

This is what i am getting:

```
<div class="row" data-v-6e4dbe9e>
 <div class="col-17 podcasts-group" data-v-6e4dbe9e>
  <div class="loading-spinner" data-v-6e4dbe9e>      //the devil himself
   <div class="spinner" data-v-ac3cb376 data-v-6e4dbe9e>
    <div class="rect1" data-v-ac3cb376></div>
    <div class="rect2" data-v-ac3cb376></div>
    <div class="rect3" data-v-ac3cb376></div>
    <div class="rect4" data-v-ac3cb376></div>
    <div class="rect5" data-v-ac3cb376></div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div mode="in-out" class="transition-group row" data-v-6e4dbe9e>
   //Here should be stuff!
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

the code that achieves this:

```
String selector = "div.podcasts-items";
Elements elem = Jsoup.connect(link).get().select(selector)
System.out.println("html: "+elem.html());
```

This is what i would like to see (copied from inspect element after the page has loaded all the content):

```
<div class="row" data-v-6e4dbe9e>
 <div class="col-17 podcasts-group" data-v-6e4dbe9e>
  <!---->  //begone evil!
  <div mode="in-out" class="transition-group row" data-v-6e4dbe9e>
   <div class="col-17 col-md-8 center-margin" data-v-6e4dbe9e="">...</div>
   <div class="col-17 col-md-8 center-margin" data-v-6e4dbe9e="">...</div>
   <div class="col-17 col-md-8 center-margin" data-v-6e4dbe9e="">...</div>
   <div class="col-17 col-md-8 center-margin" data-v-6e4dbe9e="">...</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Google doesn't help much, because every content related to spinners etc. is about javascript.

solution:

due to the fact that JSoup only loads the HTML and does not execute any javascript the page never had a chance to load the content. You would have to use an actual browser engine or a webdriver like selenium to get the data to load.

For this specific problem I was able to get the content directly via loading the Json data through this webpage's API.

Comment: Looking for this? https://www.br.de/mediathek/podcast/api/podcasts?station=Bayern%201&limit=nolimit (found via browser's Network tab)

Comment: If you're getting only the HTML markup and the site is built with JS, you won't see anything. You need a more robust solution, for instance a headless browser like PhantomJS, that can load the full page including the scripts, interpret it all, then output the whole result.

Comment: @Chris G wow, thanks. I was updating an old programm and didn't even know they have an API. I'll check it out.

Comment: Just try simple Javacript or JQUERY Ajax requests for extracting HTML . This process would let website to execute Scripts and populate the div's and now USE JSOUP for parsing HTML

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question then your best bet is to use Selenium driver. [Link to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36111805/how-to-make-jsoup-wait-for-the-complete-pageskip-a-progress-page-to-load)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Now I know why it didn't work. I think I'll use their API for this specific problem though.